# Python - Create every possibility from list

Tags: python

So I've got a list:

```
blocks = ["air", "emerald_block"]
```

with them, I create commands, and I want to replace a string in these sentences to create every possibility that can be made from the list.

**Example:**
Input:

```
max_number = 2
blocks = ["air", "emerald_block"]
```

Output:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=bridge] at @s if block ^ ^-1 ^1 minecraft:air if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:air run tp @s ^ ^ ^2
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=bridge] at @s if block ^ ^-1 ^1 minecraft:emerald_block if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:air run tp @s ^ ^ ^2
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=bridge] at @s if block ^ ^-1 ^1 minecraft:air if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:emerald_block run tp @s ^ ^ ^2
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=bridge] at @s if block ^ ^-1 ^1 minecraft:emerald_block if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:emerald_block run tp @s ^ ^ ^2
```

That's my code:

```
max_number = 2
blocks = ["air", "emerald_block"]
command = "execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=bridge] at @s {0}run tp @s ^ ^ ^{1}"
insert_string = "INSERTHERE"


def create_positions(ran, command="if block ^ ^-1 ^{} minecraft:{} "):
    cmd = ""
    cmd += command.format(ran, insert_string)
    if ran > 1:
        cmd += create_positions(ran - 1, command)
    return cmd


c = ""

for i in range(1, max_number * len(blocks) + 1):
    c += command.format(create_positions(max_number), max_number) + "\n"


print(c)

for sentence in c:
    pass
    #I think here belongs the code to replace the string
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Do you just want your script to work with this list of two things, or should it be able to, e.g. generate all combinations of commands for a list of three, four, or more things?

Comment: It might be helpful if you can explain the minecraft commands a bit more. If there were three things in your list, should each command then have another `if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:emerald_block`, but with a `3` instead of a `2` and whatever the third thing would be, e.g. `water`, like: `if block ^ ^-1 ^3 minecraft:water` (and change `2` at the very end to a `3`?). Or is the command only ever two things?

Comment: @Tim Yes I want to check if there is no block in a certain direction (3, 4 or more blocks) into one direction. (With no blocks I mean air and emerald_block). I can't simply use `if block ^ ^ ^1 minecraft:air ^ ^ ^1 minecraft:emerald_block` because if the first block is an emerald block, it wouldn't work. And if there are two emerald_blocks in that direction, it would'nt work either.

Comment: Yeah, so you want to check the blocks in for a certain distance `x`. And you basically have to check if the block `1` away is emerald or air, and if the block `2` away is emerald or air, and so on up to `x` away? And this is specifically blocks in front of you, but 1 block below you, ie what you'd be "walking on" if you moved forward?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, this is what you want:

```py
import itertools

max_number = 3

blocks = ["air", "emerald_block"]
block_check_part = "if block ^ ^-1 ^{} minecraft:{}"
single_command = "execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, name=bridge] at @s {} run tp @s ^ ^ ^{}"
commands = []

for combination in itertools.product(blocks, repeat=max_number):
    block_check_parts = [block_check_part.format(i + 1, b) for i, b in enumerate(combination)]
    block_checks_command = " ".join(block_check_parts)
    command = single_command.format(block_checks_command, max_number)
    commands.append(command)

final_command = "\n".join(commands)
print(final_command)
```

---

The `for` loop has a lot going on, so here's to explain bit-by-bit:

```py
for combination in itertools.product(blocks, repeat=max_number):
```

`itertools` is a really useful module for doing anything like this with combinations/permutations/looping through all possibilities. The `product()` function creates the **Cartesian Product** of a set of iterables. Because we want the same set of things (the `blocks` list) combined with itself a number of times, we can use the `repeat` argument.

If we print this out we can see what it's doing:

```py
>>> print(*itertools.product(blocks, repeat=max_number), sep="\n")
('air', 'air', 'air')
('air', 'air', 'emerald_block')
('air', 'emerald_block', 'air')
('air', 'emerald_block', 'emerald_block')
('emerald_block', 'air', 'air')
('emerald_block', 'air', 'emerald_block')
('emerald_block', 'emerald_block', 'air')
('emerald_block', 'emerald_block', 'emerald_block')
```

we have every combination of `'air'` and `'emerald_block'` in every position. This is the core part really, after we've created these combinations, it's just a question of looping through them and dropping them into the command template correctly:

```py
    # loop through this block combination with a number for each and make into a command
    # e.g. the combination ('air', 'emerald_block', 'air') becomes the list
    # [
    #     "if block ^ ^-1 ^1 minecraft:air",
    #     "if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:emerald_block",
    #     "if block ^ ^-1 ^3 minecraft:air",
    # ]
    block_check_parts = [block_check_part.format(i + 1, b) for i, b in enumerate(combination)]

    # join these parts together with a space between them, e.g.:
    # "if block ^ ^-1 ^1 minecraft:air if block ^ ^-1 ^2 minecraft:emerald_block if block ^ ^-1 ^3 minecraft:air"
    block_checks_command = " ".join(block_check_parts)

    # put into the main command
    command = single_command.format(block_checks_command, max_number)

    # add to the list of commands so far
    commands.append(command)

# join all these commands together into one text list
final_command = "\n".join(commands)
print(final_command)
```

---

To be honest, this seems like quite a long-winded way to do what you're trying to achieve. There may be a quicker way to do this, but I don't know the scope of Minecraft commands to be able to make a good suggestion.

I came across this though, which may be similar: https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/a8hbli/can_someone_tell_me_how_the_113_execute_if_blocks/